# How to pass values from a linked menu item in python tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-menu

How to create a variable to hold and pass label of the item selected from a drop down menu? While I'm here, may I ask how to send a second (spare) variable into a function in tkinter at the same time. I'm **not** using classes or "OptionMenu".
Here's what I have...

```
## In a tkinter I have this...

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Toplevel, Button, Tk, Menu, Frame

root = Tk()

xr, yr = 200, 170
rg = str(xr) + "x" + str(yr) # concatinating
root.geometry(rg)

selection = tk.StringVar(root)

print(f"Before option menu selected, selection.get() = {selection.get()}")

def confirm_stage(*args):
    global selection
    print(f"selection.get(): {selection.get()}")
    print(f"selection: {selection}") # Gives PY_VAR0, How to 'decode' PY_VAR0 ?
    # print(f"*selection: {*selection}") # gives and error. Cant use '*' in f-strings
    print(f"selection[0]: {selection[0]}") # gives and error: 'StringVar' object is not subscriptable   

menubar = Menu(root)
stage_menu_item = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Stage", menu=stage_menu_item) # Shows the caption
stage_menu_item.add_command(label="1", command = confirm_stage)
stage_menu_item.add_command(label="2", command = confirm_stage)

root.config(menu=menubar)

root.mainloop()
```

The "confirm_stage" appears to offer no argument to the called function. It surely can't be that each single item selected has to point to a new separate and unique function specifically written for each item in the menu, although it would work, the code would be unwieldy.

I've seen references to StringVar() which I don't fully understand, and tried to apply it but no joy, and then how would one pass a useful second accompanying variable?

UPDATE 2: - Stripped down code. I need to get the label of the menu item clicked on.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Toplevel, Button, Tk, Menu, Frame

root = Tk()
root.geometry("200x170")


def donation_fn(selection):
    
    a= clicked_r.get()
    print(f"a= {a}")
    print(f"selection= {selection}")

    b= clicked_m.get()
    print(f"b= {b}")
    print(f"selection= {selection}")



menubar = Menu(root)

clicked_r = tk.StringVar(root)
clicked_m = tk.StringVar(menubar)

list=['1 donation', '2 donations', '3 donations']

donation = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Donations", menu=donation) # Shows the caption
for _ in list: donation.add_command(label=_,  command = lambda: donation_fn(clicked_m.get()))
# port_item.add_command(label=list,  command = lambda: None)


root.config(menu=menubar)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This works:
`stage_menu_item.add_command(label="1", command = lambda: confirm_stage("1"))`

But I'd like python/thinker to pass the variable for label caption "1" instead of hard coding it. e.g. I'd like python to do something like...
`lambda: confirm_stage(ActiveMenu.Label_of_Item_chosen_in_ActiveMenu))`

and the adjusted function is...  

`def confirm_stage(choice):
    print(f"You chose: {choice}")`

Comment: "_Gives PY_VAR0, How to 'decode' PY_VAR0_": That is the name of the control variable, to get its value, you will have to use the `get()` method. Regardless, that control option is not linked to your `Menu` in anyway. Your best might still be the answer below

Comment: @ Delrius Euphoria
But get(selection) doesn't return anything. I had it as one of my debug print lines in the confirm_stage. Nothing was printed. That it gave nothing was very surprising. It suggests clicking on the menu item doesn't generate an argument at all, which would surely make menu item selections difficult, laborious to code-waffle - almost anti-pythonic so surely this cannot be the case.

Comment: Why would you expect it to print anything? `selection` is control variable but not assigned any value or any widget. It does seem quite counter intuitive, I agree, but this is just the way it is designed(for menu item callbacks to not have the text), I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to pass the menu text to the callback and don't want to do it in every call of `.add_command()`, then you can create a custom class inheriting from `tk.Menu` and override the class method `add_command()`.  Inside the override `add_command()`, you can pass the menu text to the given callback when it is being executed.

```py
import tkinter as tk

class MyMenu(tk.Menu):
    def add_command(self, **kwargs):
        callback = kwargs.pop('command', None)
        text = kwargs.get('label')
        # pass the menu text to the given callback
        super().add_command(**kwargs, command=(lambda: callback(text)) if callback else None)

root = tk.Tk()

xr, yr = 200, 170
root.geometry(f"{xr}x{yr}")

def confirm_stage(menu_text):
    print(menu_text)

menubar = tk.Menu(root)

# Use MyMenu instead of tk.Menu
stage_menu_item = MyMenu(menubar, tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Stage", menu=stage_menu_item)
stage_menu_item.add_command(label="1", command=confirm_stage)
stage_menu_item.add_command(label="2", command=confirm_stage)

root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Wow! I'm Batman-slapping myself for not wanting to use classes, as your solution is completely stunning and I consider it a work of art. I'm not being hyperbolic! It's the second time now that I'm witness to the strength of inheritance. Thank you (and everyone else) who expended some life-force to help me on the journey to reach higher levels of proficiency in python (and programming in general). My deep gratitude to you all. stackoverflow is an incredible resource and it's contributors awesome.

Comment: acw, I've been thinking, it would be super useful if I could also read the "parent option" from the menu and also run a second function when a 'sub-item' inside the menu parent category was chosen. Unfortunately I can't put these idea's into any code that looks sensible.  Do you have any pointers on how this could be achieved?
This site mentioned adding a generic 'add' command...
https://blog.teclado.com/how-to-add-menu-to-tkinter-app/
Do you think it's the right way to go?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Toplevel, Button, Tk, Menu, Frame

root = Tk()

xr, yr = 200, 170
rg = str(xr) + "x" + str(yr) # concatinating
root.geometry(rg)

# selection = tk.StringVar()

# print(f"Before option menu selected, selection.get() = {selection.get()}")

# def confirm_stage(*args):
#     global selection
#     print(f"selection.get(): {selection.get()}")
#     print(f"selection: {selection}") # Gives PY_VAR0, How to 'decode' PY_VAR0 ?
#     # print(f"*selection: {*selection}") # gives and error. Cant use '*' in f-strings
#     print(f"selection[0]: {selection[0]}") # gives and error: 'StringVar' object is not subscriptable

def confirm_stage(var):
    print(var)

menubar = Menu(root)
stage_menu_item = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Stage", menu=stage_menu_item) # Shows the caption
# stage_menu_item.add_command(label="1", command = confirm_stage)
# stage_menu_item.add_command(label="2", command = confirm_stage)
stage_menu_item.add_command(label="1", command = lambda: confirm_stage(1))
stage_menu_item.add_command(label="2", command = lambda: confirm_stage(2))

root.config(menu=menubar)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: That certainly helps, tq, but I feel there is likely to be some automated way to pass whatever label the selected menu was chosen and to use it as an argument instead of hard coding.

Answer (score 0):

The above mentioned "lambda" only solution,

```
...
stage_menu_item.add_command(label="1", command = lambda: confirm_stage(1))
...
```

seems to work with static parameters, but if you try it with a loop, eg:

```
...
for _x in range(5):
   stage_menu_item.add_command(label='Menu'+str(_x), command=lambda: confirm_stage(str(_x)))
...
```

It doesn't. "_x" is always "4" no matter what menu item you call. Don't know why.

The only way it worked for me was:

```
def _set(x:str):
    return lambda: confirm_stage(x)

...

for _x in range(5):
    stage_menu_item.add_command(label=str(_x), command=_set(str(_x)))
```

Which renders the wanted result of: "0", "1", "2", "3", "4"

If anyone can enlighten me, why the above easy solution (without _set function) is not working, go ahead.

I forgot to mention I replaced the MyMenu with tk.Menu, since I didn't liked that approach.